# Block/unblock form during angularjs $resource requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to have my form disabled every time when I perform an async call to server.
Presently I do it manually via $scope variable, that is assigned to ng-disabled attribute of my fieldset. However I thought that there must be some way to do it using HTTP interceptors? 
Please advice how to "catch" events that are happening before/after each call so I can block form using these event handlers?

Comment: Why don't use something like interceptors? http://codingsmackdown.tv/blog/2013/01/02/using-response-interceptors-to-show-and-hide-a-loading-widget/

Comment: The best way is show a processing lid on top of the form, I don't think there is an automated way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the form displayed any time there is `$http` activity (much like a loading widget would), then yes you can use interceptors for this.

Essentially, you would `$broadcast` events from `$rootScope` and catch them in a directive attached to your form, which would enable or disable the form based on which event it is handling.

This code is adapted from a [blog post](http://endlessindirection.wordpress.com/2013/05/19/angularjs-global-loading-message-with-http-interceptors/) covering a loading widget use case scenario:

```
angular.module('formApp', [])

.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('disableFormInterceptor');
})

.directive('formToggle', function() {
  return {
    link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
      var disable = function() {
        // disable form
      };
      var enable = function() {
        // enable form
      };
      $scope.$on('disableForm', disable);
      $scope.$on('enableForm', enable);
    }
  };
})

.factory('disableFormInterceptor', function($q, $rootScope) {
  var activeRequests = 0;
  var started = function() {
    if(activeRequests==0) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('disableForm');
    }    
    activeRequests++;
  };
  var ended = function() {
    activeRequests--;
    if(activeRequests==0) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('enableForm');
    }
  };
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      started();
      return config || $q.when(config);
    },
    response: function(response) {
      ended();
      return response || $q.when(response);
    },
    responseError: function(rejection) {
      ended();
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});
```